# How to? Code Android App to Change user's LOCATION SETTING to OFF?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-location

quick Android Development question on how to Code something!
I've searched for it, but the results are always messy, so I cant seem to find what I need.
Any help is greatly appreciated..

### Question:

How would I write the Code to: Turn the user's "Location" Setting to "OFF"..?
For example, in the same way that all of the "settings toggle buttons" homescreen widgets would do it, I assume - although i'm implementing it differently than that.
I simply just need the raw code that turns LOCATION to OFF.
**Also**, what permissions would I need to add in my Manifest?

THANKS IN ADVANCE! :)

Answer (score 1):

> How would I write the Code to: Turn the user's "Location" Setting to "OFF"..?

You don't, except perhaps on rooted devices or as a system app (i.e., pre-installed by the manufacturer). Ordinary apps have no ability to change the user's location settings directly.

> all of the "settings toggle buttons" homescreen widgets would do it

Only on rooted devices, or those that are supplied by the device manufacturer for their device.

Comment: Assuming that's true, how do all the Homescreen Widgets on the Playstore do it then? There are tons of "Settings Toggles" Widgets on the Playstore, and none of them require Root..?

Comment: @Ender87: "There are tons of "Settings Toggles" Widgets on the Playstore" -- name any that offer your stated feature.

Comment: Pick one, there are tons of them.. Like the "Bar" style toggle widgets that span the width of your screen, and only 1 row in height, that have all the different settings on them that you can tap to toggle it ON or OFF.. You've never seen those before? Surely you must know what I'm referring to..?

Comment: "Easy Settings Widget" by DreamAppStudio.. is one example, near the top of the list, first one I tapped on, after searching the PlayStore for "settings widget".. Your thoughts?

Comment: @Ender87: My thought is that it doesn't toggle GPS on a Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.

Comment: Well, lets remember, the new SDK implements a completely revamped Standard for how Permissions work.. So I assume (A) it would only work on PRE-Marshmallow versions of Android, and (B) if the user is running Marshmallow or later (which you can check for using code) you can return a requestPermissions call and whatnot, and implement a process of obtaining the required Permission at runtime, (assuming the Permission required doesn't fall into the newly-implemented set of "Standard Permissions" which can still be simply registered in the manifest).. What do you think of all that?

Comment: @Ender87: I think that the relevant permission (`WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`) is one that you cannot hold except from an app that is signed by the firmware's signing key. I think that Easy Settings Widget does not toggle GPS on a Nexus 4 running Android 5.1. I think that Easy Settings Widget and kin use old security flaws that have since been fixed. And I think that if you point me to an app that can toggle whether GPS is enabled on Android 4.4 or higher that I will happily figure out how it does it, so I can get that new security flaw fixed.

Comment: While I understand the concnern over the ability to do such a thing via code, I would think the ability should still remain, but with a simple dialog requesting the user to grant permission for the app to do what it's attempting to do, at the time of the code execution, dont you think? I mean, having a "Settings Toggle" Widget on your homescreen is pretty common (or at least it used to be), and isn't exactly out of the realm of a typical action for an App to be able to execute (again, even if it requires a permission dialog to pop-up for the user to say "ok" to each time). Well hm

Comment: PS.. What about registering (or requesting to register) your App under the user's "system administrators", similar to the way that Launchers (like Nova, etc) have to do in order to gain access to be able to pull your notification bar down via gesture you set in the Nova preferences, etc. etc.. It requires a special permission to be granted before Nova is able to execute that action (again, for example, expanding the notifications bar)..
..Would this be a route I could take to get my idea to work?